# Good online TFS solution

Tags: webapp-rec

We're starting a software development project and since we won't be working together (same building) we're looking for an integrated [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) solution.

Does anybody know of a good one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try Team System Web Access (TSWA). Channel 9 did a video on it that might serve as a good introduction: [A first look at Visual Studio Team System Web Access 2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/VisualStudio/A-first-look-at-Visual-Studio-Team-System-Web-Access-2010)

There is also list of hosting solutions here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/hosting

Comment: What if I don't have a public IP to expose TSWA? I want a site (like Assembla for instance) that allow us to work with TFS

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. Did you mean to ask for TFS hosting solutions? There is a list of hosting solutions here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/hosting

Comment: @sebastien, @Bernhard, if the tick is for the answer in the comment, it's probably worth moving it into the main answer...